# How restore from ASM to a new server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm

We have a machine that crashed completely. 
The ASM disks are fine. Is it possible to mount the old ASM disks to a new machine and then restore the datafiles/redo files/ control files/everything to the new database?

Please note I don't want to restore from backup. I need to restore everything on ASM disks to new hardware with fresh OS and fresh database installation. 
Is that possible? if yes, how?

We are running Oracle 11gR1 database on Redhat Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RMAN for this.
There is some documentation I suggest you read in order to accomplish this easy way:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e18951/asm_rman.htm

Comment: Hi Anthony, How do we do that if I had my files(datafiles and others) stored on file system rather than ASM?

Answer (score 0):

If you had everything (spfile, control file, redo logs and datafiles) on ASM then you can just install the same Oracle version to new machine, mount ASM diskgroups, point pfile to spfile on ASM, create password file and run the database without any restore.
Oracle does not put anything special in ORACLE_HOME.